# Include <script type="text/javascript">.....</script> in js variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I am trying to include the following script in a variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[Calendar.setup({
inputField : "datum",trigger    : "f_btn1",onSelect   : function() {this.hide() },dateFormat : "%Y-%m-%d "});//]]></script>*

var contentString ='<table><tr><td><input size="10" id="datum" /><button id="f_btn1">ddd</td></tr> </table> <script type="text/javascript">..see above script...</script>';
```

The browser generates an error in the line with `</script>`. I cannot place the script because it should be executed only if a  window opens in google maps --> `infowindow.open(map,marker1);`

Is it generally possible to put the declaration of js in a variable? I have tried several combinations of commas and escape variations (\") but wasn't successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser will read the `</script>` tag inside the string, and assume that you're closing the JavaScript block entirely.
So if you write:

```
<script> var a = '</script>'; </script>
```

…it is not read as

```
<script>
  var a = '</script>';
</script>
```

But as

```
<script>
  var a = '
</script>'; </script>
```

Usually people solve this by just splitting up the  tag and concatenating it:

```
<script> var a = '</scr' + 'ipt>'; </script>
```

Comment: I could solve the issue by splitting the closing script tag. thanks